# По методологии DDD, что является в диаграмме объектом

Tags: java, ddd, модель-данных

Как я понимаю, `Entity` обозначают в виде класса, а как обозначают `ValueObject`?

Класс **Погода**:

```
public class Погода {

public Метеоэлемент m_Метеоэлемент;
public Прогноз m_Прогноз;
public Погода(){ }
public Метеоэлемент(){ }
}
```

Класс **Факт**:

```
public class Факт extends Погода {

private Data Дата наблюдения;
```

Класс **Метеоэлемент**:

```
public class Метеоэлемент {

public Температура m_Температура;
public Температура воды, град. m_Температура воды, град.;
public Ветер m_Ветер;
public Облачность m_Облачность;
}
```

Класс **Температура**:

```
public class Температура {

private int Температура воздуха, град;
public Температура(){ }
}
```

Comment: Чет вот это: public class Факт extends Погода {, вообще мимо. Должно быть что то типа такого: public class Факт {
 private Data датаНаблюдения;
 private Погода погода;
}

Comment: @ezhov_da почему так?

Comment: Класс Факт, это скорее сущность, которая имеет свою ID, в данном случае в виде даты и в последствии может быть использована в статистике или анализе. Погода же - это объект значение из которого строятся факты. То есть Факт это из разряда статистических данных, а не погодных.

Comment: ezhov_da т.е. Факт - entity, а Погода - обьект-значения? А тогда метеоэлемент что это? температура что это?

Comment: Тоже объект-значение.

Comment: @ezdov_da а можете подсказать, если Температураобъект-значения, как обозначают обьект значения на диаграмме? как обозначают в коде? Это переменная? Класса Метеоэлемент?

Comment: На UML диаграмме? Как Class. В коде это обычный класс. В Вашем случае  так же поле класса Метеоэлемент.

Comment: @ezhov_da, т.е. метеоэлемент - это класс, а температура воздуха это поле класса Метеоэлемент?  И еще уточнение, а на диаграмме, тогда не композицией связывать, просто сделать ввиде поля? Или в отдельном классе все таки хранить значение температуры и связать с метеоэлементом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80910/discussion-between-ezhov-da-and-kirumit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вопрос сложный и крупный. Кратко есть [тут](https://habr.com/post/275599/), копипастить не хочу.
2. VO обычно свойство класса, реже бывают классы (например, класс Money = prop Value + prop Currency), опознать можно по отсутствию Id (но это неточно, т.к. одни и те же вещи могут выступать как Entity, так и VO в разных сценариях)